What 2D clustering algorithms should I use for overlapping boxes?
I have data represented as two-dimensional, overlapping boxes, and I need to check every pair of overlapping boxes for some similarity metrics. This is an $O(n^2)$ problem when done naïvely, so I'd like to find a reasonable way to partition these into smaller groups that will exclude non-matches.
Because the size of these boxes leads to a lot of overlap, I'd like to insert all boxes into a data structure that will partition into groups that I can check independently. Unfortunately, my recollection of those algorithms is rather weak. I've briefly looked into spatial hashing, AABB- and quad-trees, etc., but they don't seem applicable in my case.
For example, quad-trees seem to give the ability to find entities matching a particular query space. I don't have a specific target space to query but instead, I want to ask the data structure for groups of records that are proximal (perhaps looking at $n$ of the groups that have at least $m$ overlapping boxes).
What are some relevant data structures for this automatic (probably hierarchical) task?

While not knowing a helpful data structure, look at algorithms: Would line sweeping help?
